# Using VBS to call text file to populate to field in email

Tags: email, vbscript

I am creating a script to be placed on servers to run without user interaction that will send an email when certain criteria are met.  I have the criteria script running, but I want to make the script easy to deploy and modify for each individual server.

I am trying to make the script make a call to a text file to populate the TO field in the email.  The text file will have the email addresses placed one per line (I was putting a semicolon on the end of the addresses since I know multiple TO addresses are separated by semicolons)

I have tried a number of different variations on calling the script and I either get an error on the To line, or it makes it through the script and I get an error that no recipients were defined.  Here is the script below:

```
`Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFileEmailAddresses = objFSO.OpenTextFile("EmailAddresses.txt", 1)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")

ServicesArray = Split (objFileEmailAddresses.ReadAll, vbNewLine)

For Each strService In ServicesArray
    objDictionary.Add strService, strService
Next



Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "email@server.com"
objEmail.To = objFileEmailAddresses
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp address"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = "High"
objEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Priority") = 2
objEmail.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:httpmail:importance") = 2
objEmail.Fields.Update
objEmail.Subject = "Primary Server " & Ucase(strComputerName) & " is Rebooting Now"
objEmail.TextBody ="The primary server " & Ucase(strComputerName) & " is scheduled to reboot at this time.  The server will be offline in less than one minute.  .... "
objEmail.Send

objFileEmailAddresses.Close()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `To` field of your `objEmail` object should be a string containing one or more e-mail addresses. You're assigning a TextStream object (`objFileEmailAddresses`) to it.

You said your e-mail addresses already end with a semicolon? Try this instead:

```
' Open the text file containing all of the e-mail addresses...
Set objFileEmailAddresses = objFSO.OpenTextFile("EmailAddresses.txt", 1)

' Read the entire file. Replace newlines with nothing to get a single
' string of semicolon-separated e-mail addresses...
strAddresses = Replace(objFileEmailAddresses.ReadAll, vbCrLf, "")

' Assign the string to the e-mail object...
objEmail.To = strAddresses
```

You can get rid of the `Dictionary` object. Unless you're afraid you may have the same e-mail addresses listed more than once, in which case we may need to use one.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it!